# Do the @Configuration and @Bean annotations work in this code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working for an Internet company.Recently I have a problem in a configuration file of the SpringMVC.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    public WebConfig() {
    }
    protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
        ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        if (ClassUtils.isPresent("javax.xml.bind.Binder", classLoader)) {
            converters.add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
        }
        if (ClassUtils.isPresent("com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper", classLoader)) {
            converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        }
        StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
        stringConverter.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);
        converters.add(stringConverter);
        converters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter());
    }
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter = super.requestMappingHandlerAdapter();
        List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> handlers = new ArrayList();
        handlers.add(new ModelAndViewMethodReturnValueHandler());
        handlers.add(new ModelMethodProcessor());
        handlers.add(new ViewMethodReturnValueHandler());
        handlers.add(new HttpEntityMethodProcessor(this.getMessageConverters()));
        handlers.add(new ModelAttributeMethodProcessor(false));
        handlers.add(new NullableRequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor(this.getMessageConverters()));
        handlers.add(new ViewNameMethodReturnValueHandler());
        handlers.add(new MapMethodProcessor());
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(adapter.getModelAndViewResolvers())) {
            handlers.add(new ModelAndViewResolverMethodReturnValueHandler(adapter.getModelAndViewResolvers()));
        } else {
            handlers.add(new ModelAttributeMethodProcessor(true));
        }
        adapter.setReturnValueHandlers(handlers);
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

This class is coming from external jar package.

In my mvc-core-config.xml there is a line:

```
<bean class="com.wosai.upay.common.config.WebConfig"/>
```

I want to know if these spring annotations work in this class?

Comment: As i understand you mean @Configuration,

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you mean `@Configuration`,if it so, this class will be a configuration class in two cases
1) You will add the pass to this class in your Dispatcher Servlet
2) In the main configuration file(class that anotated with `@EnableWebMvc`) you will import this class using `@Import` or if you put `@ComponentScan` this class will be scan automatically